# Rails, Count and Group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a table like:

```
 +--------+-----------+-------+-----------+
 |house_no|house_alpha|flat_no|street_name|
 +--------+-----------+-------+-----------+
 |       1|           |       |James St   |
 |       1|           |       |James St   |
 |       1|           |       |James St   |
 |       2|          A|       |James St   |
 |       2|          B|       |James St   |
 |       3|          A|       |James St   |
 |       4|           |    416|James St   |
 |       4|           |    416|James St   |
 +--------+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

And I'm trying to count the number of different addresses in this table.
This returns the distinct addresses:

```
Address.all(:select => 'street_name, flat_no, house_no, house_alpha',
            :group => 'street_name, flat_no, house_no, house_alpha').length
```

But I want to do it on the SQL end. and trying to combine count and group doesn't like me. I'm clearly doing something wrong.

(Database is postgres, rails is 2.x).

Comment: You mean that `Address.count(:group => 'street_name, flat_no, house_no, house_alpha', :distinct => true)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that there's a pretty Rails way to do a count across grouped columns. There are plenty of weird ways to do this in SQL, but this way is easy enough to follow.

```
Address.find(:all, 
             :select => "count(*) as addr_count", 
             :having => "addr_count > 0", 
             :group => 'street_name, flat_no, house_no, house_alpha').size
```

That will run the following SQL query.

```
SELECT count(*) as addr_count FROM "addresses" GROUP BY street_name, flat_no, house_no, house_alpha HAVING addr_count > 0
```

**Edit: Read this for Postgres**

From the comments below, here is the way to do the above on Postgres.

```
Address.find(:all, 
             :select => "count(*)", 
             :having => "count(*) > 0", 
             :group => 'street_name, flat_no, house_no, house_alpha').size
```

This generates the following query.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM "addresses" GROUP BY street_name, flat_no, house_no, house_alpha HAVING count(*) > 0
```

Comment: is addr_count a magic thing? or do I need to add a column for this? What you've written doesn't work.

Comment: addr_count is just a SQL alias, and nothing magical. It does not represent a column. Please post your console output and logs as a way to explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Also, does your table have an id column?

Comment: You can't use the column alias in the HAVING - you need to repeat the count(*) expression, making it "... HAVING count(*) > 0". It might be possible to just change that in the :having specification - I don't know rails so I can't comment on that part.

Comment: @Magnus Is this a postgres thing? The code I posted absolutely works on sqlite3.

Comment: Yes, it's a postgres thing. I think it applies to some other databases as well, but not all of them.

Comment: I never actually ended up using this, and left it as the going through rails. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 7):

For rails 3 with Arel, you could do the following:

```
Address.group(:street_name, :flat_no, :house_no, :house_alpha).having("count(*) > 0").count.size
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Rails 2**, I have found the `:group` option to not behave reliably (in my latest case, it made an array of only the first record in each group).  As an alternative, you might combine your db search with `EnumerableArray#group_by` as follows:

```
addresses = Address.find(:all, 
             :select => "count(*) as addr_count", 
             :having => "addr_count > 0"), 
grouped_addrs = addresses.group_by{|a| [a.street_name, a.flat_no, a.house_no, a.house_alpha] }
```